# Analog Clock Problem; Alignment of the Hour Hand and Minute Hand.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, puzzle

The question goes like this:

> It is now between 9 and 10 o’clock. In 4 minutes, the hour hand will be directly opposite the position occupied by the minute hand 3 minutes ago. What time is it now?

The answer to this question is **9:20**, but cannot figure out the solution. I've tried treating this as a distance problem. I used degrees(°) as the distance unit, so the hour hand has a speed of $\frac12°$ per minute and the minute hand $6°$ per minute. It did not help me at all.

Maybe I just needed to be pointed to the right direction. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will measure angles in degrees from $12:00$ in a clockwise direction.

Let $h(t)$ be the position of the hour hand, in degrees, at $t$ minutes after $9$:$00$ and let $m(t)$ be the position of the minute hand, in degrees, at $t$ minutes after $9$:$00$.

Then $$h(t) = 270 + \frac 12t$$

and $$m(t) = 6t$$

We need to solve

\begin{align}
   h(t+4) &= m(t-3) + 180 \\
   270 + \frac 12(t+4) &= 6(t-3) + 180 \\
   t &= 20\; \text{minutes}
\end{align}